# Converting a string month day, year to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: python, pandas

I need to covert a string which contains date information (e.g., `November 3, 2020`) into date format (i.e., `11/03/2020`).
I wrote

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%y'))
```

where `Date` is

```
November 3, 2020
June 26, 2002
July 02, 2010
```

and many other dates, but I found the error ValueError: NaTType does not support strftime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.dt.strftime`, which handles the `NaT`:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['November 3, 2020',
         'June 26, 2002',
         'July 02, 2010',
         'NaT']

dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Date'])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
       Date
0  11/03/20
1  06/26/02
2  07/02/10
3       NaN
```